# How to import Databricks mount using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, databricks, mount, terraform-provider-databricks

I want to import existing Databricks infrastructure to Terraform, but I can't import existing mounts. I have a mount to the S3 bucket on AWS which is as follows: `dbfs:/mnt/copyprod`. According to the official documentation of databricks provider this command should work:

`$ terraform import databricks_mount.this <mount_name>`

I have created appropriate resource block

```
resource "databricks_mount" "copyprod" {
 ...
}
```

but when I try to run command `terraform import databricks_mount.copyprod copyprod`, which worked for other resources, I always get the same error:

```
databricks_mount.copyprod: Importing from ID "copyprod"...
databricks_mount.copyprod: Import prepared!
  Prepared databricks_mount for import
databricks_mount.copyprod: Refreshing state... [id=copyprod]
╷
│ Error: value of name is not specified or empty
```

What "value of name" is this? Where should I specify it? As I understand there is no need to define arguments in the resource block for import to work as it only updates `.tfstate` file, but even if I do (such as defining `name`, `bucket_name` etc.), the error is always the same. I also tried to pass `<mount_name>` in different styles, but with no luck. How can I make this work?

Connection to Databricks is rather correct, as I can import other resources such as clusters or notebooks. I am using Terraform v1.0.9 and Databricks provider v0.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the provider, and it looks like that it doesn't work correctly for a some time (although with different error) - I've tested with old implementations (`databricks_aws_s3_mount` and `databricks_azure_adls_gen2_mount`) on 0.3.5 & 0.3.10 (versions before `databricks_mount` resource was added).

Please report this issue on [Github](https://github.com/databrickslabs/terraform-provider-databricks/issues) (mention me in the text), I'll look into it early next week, or maybe over weekend if I have time.

Comment: Thank you for your reply - I created an issue, as you asked.
https://github.com/databrickslabs/terraform-provider-databricks/issues/1018